# SELECT rows HAVING result equal to a list of values from DISTINCT

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I want to return results matching a `key` where all `parts` are present.  Given:

```
create table things (
  id int not null,
  key int not null,
  part character varying(1),
  details character varying(64),
  CONSTRAINT things_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );
```

And this:

| id | key | part | details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a | 1a details |
| 2 | 1 | b | 1b details |
| 3 | 1 | c | 1c details |
| 4 | 2 | a | 2a details |
| 5 | 2 | b | 2b details |
| 6 | 2 | c | 2c details |
| 7 | 3 | a | 3a details |
| 8 | 3 | c | 3c details |
| 9 | 4 | b | 4b details |
| 10 | 5 | b | 5b details |
| 11 | 6 | b | 6b details |
| 12 | 6 | c | 6c details |
| 13 | 7 | a | 7a details |
| 14 | 8 | a | 8a details |

I can get to this:

| id | key | part | details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a | 1a details |
| 2 | 1 | b | 1b details |
| 3 | 1 | c | 1c details |
| 4 | 2 | a | 2a details |
| 5 | 2 | b | 2b details |
| 6 | 2 | c | 2c details |

With this query:

```
select * 
from things t
where t.key in (
  select x.key
  from things x
  group by x.key
  having count(distinct part) = 3
);
```

But I really want to match the distinct part, not just the count of it, e.g. `having distinct part = ['a', 'b', 'c']`.  Can I do this in the query or just do it in the application code?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/38b399/6

### Edit

Essentially, what I'm after is a chunk of rows where all the `part`s for a `thing` are present.  There are eight parts to a thing.  They'll be processed and the records in this table deleted.  Repeat forever.

Here is the `CREATE` script from pgAdmin (with reduced noise):

```
CREATE TABLE public.things (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    key character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    part character varying(3) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    details character varying(1024) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    timezone character varying(128) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    client_id uuid,
    CONSTRAINT things_client_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (client_id)
        REFERENCES public.clients (id)

);

CREATE INDEX things_client_id_index ON public.things (client_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_things ON public.things (key, part, client_id);
```

Comment: What is the issue with your query?

Comment: whats your original issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: Please clarify your *exact* filter requirements, and the exact result you are looking for. And always disclose your version of Postgres, please.

Comment: Is `(key, part)` defined `UNIQUE`? If so, is there a `UNIQUE` constraint (like there should be)? Is there a `keys` table? A `FOREIGN KEY` constraint pointing to it?

Comment: Can you show us the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this can be cast as a case of [relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division).

Queries checking the distinct count of parts per key have to process *all* rows of the table. Plus, a *distinct* count is expensive on top of that. Aggregating and comparing arrays is even more expensive.

If most rows qualify, that does not make a big difference as the whole table will be processed anyway. For a small selection, any such approach performs terribly. Alternative query techniques that can use **indexes** will shine in comparison.

Ideally, you have a separate table of keys with one row per relevant key. Then use something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   keys k
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM things WHERE key = k.key AND part = 'a')
AND    EXISTS (SELECT FROM things WHERE key = k.key AND part = 'b')
AND    EXISTS (SELECT FROM things WHERE key = k.key AND part = 'c');
```

Table `things` needs a multicolumn index on `(part, key)` to make it fast.

Even if you don't have a `keys` table:

```sql
SELECT t1.key
FROM   things t1
JOIN   things t2 USING (key)
JOIN   things t3 USING (key)
WHERE  t1.part = 'a'
AND    t2.part = 'b'
AND    t3.part = 'c';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ffabe5f29888136e29a8e8e110bd33b6)*

The best query depends on your *exact* requirements for filters and result format, and the *exact* schema definition.

Related:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)

Comment: Do you mean insert same key into keys and things table, without creating a relation between the two tables?

Comment: dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b7e4bb23ee0d91d4976f64c6868ec118)

Comment: The query does not care about any `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. But from a DB design perspective, a FK is the clean way to do this, of course. Enforces referential integrity.

Answer (score 0):

I think `count(distinct)` does what you want.  If you wanted to explicitly specify the parts, you could use:

```
where t.key in (
  select x.key
  from things x
  group by x.key
  having array_agg(distinct part order by part)::text[] = array['a', 'b', 'c']
);
```